# Strange behavior with Json Serialization of dictionary key in camelcase using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver to serialize the object into json. I see strange property name conversion of dictionary key.

Why key change `DEMO => demo` but `DEMO Long => demO Long`(capital O instead of small o) ?

More Tests:

```
Dictionary Key        Json Property Name(After serialization)
------------          ----------------
THISISMYKEY           thisismykey
DEMO                  demo
DEMO Long             demO Long
LONGDEMOKAY           longdemokay
OOOO oOOOoo           oooO oOOOoo
```

C# Code for Reference :

```
Dictionary<string, long> collection = new Dictionary<string, long>();
collection.Add("THISISMYKEY", 100);
collection.Add("DEMO", 200);
collection.Add("thisissmallkey", 300);
collection.Add("LONGDEMOKAY", 400);
collection.Add("THISISOTHER", 500);
collection.Add("OOOO oOOOoo", 600);
collection.Add("DEMO Long", 700);

var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection, new JsonSerializerSettings{
  ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have the last version of Newtonsoft.Json, with the version 12.0.3, I have this result related from your example:

```
{"thisismykey":100,"demo":200,"thisissmallkey":300,"longdemokay":400,"thisisother":500,"oooo oOOOoo":600,"demo Long":700}
```

I don't see any issue ?